# Rendered video having black layer

Tags: animation

[image]

[image]

I just modified a blender file but after rendering I am getting these black extra layers on the video. How can I remove it. Thanks

To be honest I downloaded the blender file and modified it i have 1% knowledge about this. Please download my blender file and help me thanks.
https://www.mediafire.com/file/edmq98ye4lavy9v/my_best_V2%281%29.blend/file

The first screen shot i am getting that black layer while playing the video and the second screenshot I am getting that black layer at the end of the video.

Comment: Think of your question like this: no one was looking over your shoulder when you created your project. We don't know what you modified or what the project was like before you modified it... in other words be kind enough to explain what it is we are looking at, what elements the scene contains, what kind of nodes you are using in the compositor, what render engine you are using, how you organized your layers. No one in this site has super powers to guess any of that. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information.

Comment: Welcome, TimePassNG. Are you rendering to MP4 directly? If something went wrong in the middle of the rendering, you may get strange artifacts in your final video. The better way to do it is: render sprites in png or jpeg, if something went wrong, you can re-render the affected png/jpeg file only. Then use the video editor to render the final video.

Comment: If you want to upload files for us to check, please use blend-exchange (30 MB max.) and not dropbox or other random file sharing sites. Your questions and our answers might become useless, once the link to the file breaks.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqgW_u3Idlk&feature=youtu.be See this video there is black layer on the video how can I remove it. I tried png method also black layer is there.